# I get a blank echo from regex

Tags: regex, string, bash, echo

If I run this file, it works fine and outputs the lines I expect:

```
workspaceFile=`cat tensorflow/workspace.bzl`
echo $workspaceFile | grep -oP '\/[a-z0-9]{12}.tar.gz'
```

However, if I run this, all I get is blank output in the terminal:

```
workspaceFile=`cat tensorflow/workspace.bzl`
TAR_FILE_WITH_SLASH=$workspaceFile | grep -oP '\/[a-z0-9]{12}.tar.gz'
echo $TAR_FILE_WITH_SLASH
```

The file is quite long so I'll add a shortened version here for simplicity's sake:

```
tf_http_archive(
  name = "eigen_archive",
  urls = [
    "https://mirror.bazel.build/bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/get/6913f0cf7d06.tar.gz",
    "https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/get/6913f0cf7d06.tar.gz",
  ],
```

Comment: Use `TAR_FILE_WITH_SLASH="$(echo $workspaceFile | grep -oP '/[a-z0-9]{12}\.tar\.gz')"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `$()` syntax, echo the contents of `workspaceFile` and then pipe the `grep` command:

```
TAR_FILE_WITH_SLASH="$(echo $workspaceFile | grep -oE '/[a-z0-9]{12}\.tar\.gz')"
```

Also, note you need no PCRE regex here, you can use a POSIX ERE regex (that is, replace `P` with `E`). You may even use a POSIX BRE pattern here, like `grep -o '/[a-z0-9]\{12\}\.tar\.gz'`. The dot must be escaped to match a literal dot and the `/` is not special here and needs no escaping.

See the [online demo](http://rextester.com/HYTVM61655).

Comment: I know this is an additional question, but the final, desired output would be only 1 with the leading "/" removed?

Comment: You mean you want to get rid of `/`? Use `grep -oP '/\K[a-z0-9]{12}\.tar\.gz'`

Comment: Yes exactly, and to only match the first occurrence of the regex (there are 2 in this particular example).

Comment: Ok, use [`grep -oP '/\K[a-z0-9]{12}\.tar\.gz' | head -1`](http://rextester.com/XSUR20862).

Comment: Perfect thank you! Man I'd love to have your regex knowledge :)

Answer (score 0):

What's about the path?

```
workspaceFile=`cat ~/tensorflow/workspace.bzl`
```